# Simple task: I want what happens after clicking "try it" to happen without actually needing to click on the button

Tags: time

Here:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GMNZXF3GUAGT

As you can see, it converts time AFTER you have to click on the button, I want it to show the output without needing to click on "try it" and the unconverted time to be hidden, so I just want the converted time to show when the user enters my website (not as alert, but in the content normally)

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example, you just need to remove the code in the  tags from the function.

Eg:

```
<script> 
  var theDate = new Date(Date.parse('06/14/2020 4:41:48 PM UTC')); 

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Local date Time: "+theDate.toLocaleString(); 
</script>
```

Then you code will run whenever the page loads and not onclick. To remove the unconverted time and button you just need to remove them from the HTML.

Thanks,

EDIT - CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  
<head> 
    <title> 
        How to convert UTC date time 
        into local date time? 
    </title> 
  
    <style> 
        h1 { 
            color: green; 
        } 
  
        body { 
            text-align: center; 
        } 
    </style> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <h1>GeekforGeeks</h1> 
  
    <p id="demo"></p> 
  
    <script> 
      var theDate = new Date(Date.parse( 
        '06/14/2020 4:41:48 PM UTC')); 

      document.getElementById("demo") 
        .innerHTML = "Local date Time: " 
        + theDate.toLocaleString(); 
    </script> 
</body> 
  
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking for much, can you do it for me in a W3school page like I'm showing?

Comment: Hello, I have added the code, all you need to do is copy and paste. Thanks,

Comment: Did this code  convert the time in your timezone as well?

Comment: It did, if you want the current date use var ```theDate = new Date();``` instead of var the ```var theDate = new Date(Date.parse('06/14/2020 4:41:48 PM UTC'));;```

Comment: No, I want to do it for specific times. Jack, I can't tell you how much you just helped me here. It was simple for you because you are a pro, but believe it or not, I've been spending DAYS to do this LOL as I'm no coder, but wanted to do this on my website.

Thank you a TON man. Wish you everything in the world, stay safe and THANKS again, I really appreciate your time :) <3

Comment: No problem my friend, have a great day